# Grabbing error message from Firebase Login Authentication in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to get the exact error message from error return by firebase . The print statement of the error is this :

```
 Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17008 "The email address is badly formatted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is badly formatted., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL})
```

I want to grab the string : `"The email address is badly formatted."` and show it in `SVprogressHUD` with error: This is what i did :

`SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "\(String(describing: error))")`

The `SVprogressHUD` shows but with the entire message below:

```
 "Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17008 "The email address is badly formatted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is badly formatted., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL})
```

How can just grap the message string `"The email address is badly formatted."`?

Comment: Try`error.localizedDescription`

Answer (score 0):

This message is contained in `localizedDescription` property of error object so try

```
SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error.localizedDescription)
```

If your error is optional, do an optional binding with

```
if let error = error {
  SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error.localizedDescription)
}
```